# Apply style to child that are under certain element

Tags: maui

I have a `ContentPage` (page1) containing a couple of input fields. I define `Style` for the fields at the top of the `ContentPage` so I can apply the same style to all of them.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="page1">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Spacing" Value="4"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <!-- input field-->
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Name"/>
        <Border>
            <Entry Text="{Binding UserName}"
                   Placeholder="Enter name..."/>
        </Border>
    </StackLayout>

    <!-- more fields here -->
</ContentPage>
```

I have another `ContentPage` (page2), which has the same `Style` settings for inputs in it.
To avoid duplicating code, I want to define the `Style` settings once somehere (e.g. App.xaml) and use it everywhere.

A solution I know is define `Style` with a key. Something like:

```
<Style TargetType="StackLayout" x:Key="InputFieldStyle">
```

and set the key to elements.
But this requires me to set the key to every elements I want to apply it to.
I also need to do the same for all the child elements under the `StackLayout`.

I was wondering if there is a way of applying style to child elements only when they are under certain element.
For instance, if `Border` is under this particular `StackLayout`, apply `Style X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by selecting direct **child** element:`Border` of certain **root** element: `VerticalStackLayout`. Below is the detailed step for your reference:

**Step 1:**
Add an empty CSS file to your .NET MAUI app project. The CSS file(**styles.css**) can be placed in any folder, with the Resources/Styles folder being the recommended location. Set the build action of the CSS file to `MauiCss`.

**Step 2:**
Load the style sheet in XAML like below:

```
<Application.Resources> 
      <ResourceDictionary>
            <StyleSheet Source="/Resources/Styles/styles.css" />
            ...Omitted for brevity
      </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Step 3:**
Direct child elements in the visual tree can be selected with the case insensitive element>element selector like below:

**styles.css**

```
VerticalStackLayout > border { 
    stroke: #C49B33;
    stroke-width: 4;
    background: #2B0B98;
    padding:16,8;
}
```

**TestPage.xaml**

```
<VerticalStackLayout> 
        <Border>
            <Label Text=".NET MAUI"
           TextColor="White"
           FontSize="18"
           FontAttributes="Bold" />

        </Border>
     
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Below is the output:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [Select direct child elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/css?view=net-maui-7.0#select-direct-child-elements);

Answer (score 0):

Try local resources with [implicit styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0#implicit-styles) (a style without a key) based on  [inherited styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0#style-inheritance):

Styles:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="checkBoxStyleA" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <!-- Setters -->
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="checkBoxStyleB" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <!-- Setters -->
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <!-- the following style should be applied to all CheckBoxes in this StackLayout -->
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource checkBoxStyleA}" />
    </StackLayout.Resources>
    <CheckBox />
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <!-- the following style should be applied to all CheckBoxes in this StackLayout -->
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource checkBoxStyleB}" />
    </StackLayout.Resources>
    <CheckBox />
</StackLayout>
```

The styles in `ContentPage.Resources` above might be placed in the `Application.Resources` `ResourceDictionary` and targeting a common base class of `Button` and `CheckBox` like `VisualElement` containing the property `BackgroundColor`:

```
<Application.Resources> 
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="styleA" TargetType="VisualElement">
      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="styleB" TargetType="VisualElement">
      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

Usage:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <!-- style applied to all Buttons in this StackLayout -->
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleA}" />

        <!-- style applied to all CheckBoxes in this StackLayout -->
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleA}" />
    </StackLayout.Resources>
    <CheckBox />
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <!-- style applied to all Buttons in this StackLayout -->
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleB}" />

        <!-- style applied to all CheckBoxes in this StackLayout -->
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleB}" />
    </StackLayout.Resources>
    <CheckBox />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: That only works for the same TargetType. I'm looking for a way to apply style when the parent is X, apply style Y to element Z. Besides, your solution needs to be defined in each content page, which I'm trying to avoid.